# Create Intellij IDEA plugin. Store plugin settings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am new at IDEA plugin development and I have a plugin that I need to support. Now there are some settings for this plugin. I want to create settings that will be stored at the project level, but I don't know how to do this.

I have created the UI part:

```
class SettingsPanel implements Configurable
```

but I don't understand how I can store some information on project level and use this information in my action for example. I want to show project folders structure at my settings panel and save selected folder name.

Comment: I'm having trouble even getting up to that point - could you provide a link to some documentation which explains how to add the UI to the Settings menu/system?

Comment: this looks like a good place to start - http://corochann.com/intellij-plugin-development-introduction-applicationconfigurable-projectconfigurable-873.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Persisting State of Components](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/persisting_state_of_components.html) should answer your questions